# Variables in rakefile not visible in test classes

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, watir

Thanks to help I've received here, I have a test suite of ruby tests that are in a CI server continually verifying or UI (using Watir). However a new requirement came in, which actually highlighted a bug in the CI setup.

So in the rakefile I have the following

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require './modules/utilities'
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/minitest'

randomId = 1 + rand(100000)
Server ||= "http://someserver_hostname:8080/login.html"
NormalUser = "watir" + randomId.to_s + "_normal"
AdminUser = "watir" + randomId.to_s + "_admin"
Password = "Watir_" + randomId.to_s

Rake::TestTask.new(:runtests) do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['./**/Test*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end 

task :testSetup do
  Server = "http://#{ENV["server"]}:8080/login.html"
  p "Using the following server\n\n#{Server}\n\n"
  #Lets create our own user for these tests
  createNormalUser(NormalUser, Password)
  createAdminUser(AdminUser, Password)
end

task :testCleanUp do
  #Delete our own user
  deleteUser(NormalUser)
  deleteUser(AdminUser)
end


task :runAllTests => [:testSetup,:runtests, :testCleanUp]
```

The goal is that someone can manually run the build in Jenkins and specify (via dropdown list) which server to run the tests against. I have all that set up and the users are created in the selected server. The problem is that the tests are run using a hardcoded Server variable elsewhere in the ruby scripts, which is defined as

```
Server ||= "http://Server_hostname:8080/login.html"
```

Which if I read it correctly, will only reassign Server if it isn't already defined, which is exactly what I need. The problem is that if I remove this definition, then Server is undefined. If I leave it in, the tests will run against this hostname and not the one that I have defined in the rakefile. Obviously I have fecked up somewhere, but I can't see why the Server set in the rakefile isn't visible in the test scripts given that it is all one process
Thanks

I should add that the createXXUser methods and deleteUser methods all work correctly, ie have the correct values for Server, NormalUser, Password etc

Comment: I do not have much experience with rakefiles. However, doing a quick test locally, I believe it is a scoping issue (ie the `Server` defined in your rakefile) does not exist in the scope of your test case. Hence, the test cases will always see `Server` as not defined and use the hard-coded value. I am surprised your test cases do not throw an exception for trying to dynamically assigning a constant.

Comment: Are you trying to access `Server` in a `Test::Unit` test?  What you're doing here is pretty confusing.  Variables defined in a Rake task are not going to be visible outside the file.  There's no reason you'd ever want to `require test/unit` in a Rake task either.  Also, you should never use CapitalCamelCase for variables.  By convention, that is reserved for class/module names.  It's not your problem, but I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here.  If you've got some normal unit tests somewhere, the Rakefile is not the place to configure them.